# (ViewPagerIndicator) Fragment doesn't change on button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have faced such problem. I'm working on an application using ViewPagerIndicator library by Jake Wharton. I would like to change fragment on button click (fragments do change when user swipes through pages though), but my code doesn't work. Any ideas for solving that? In my code below I tried changing FirstFragment to SecondFragment on rightButton click. I would be grateful for any of your help...

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
    rightButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment).commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I change fragments when swiping using this code(I don't know, if it's related to the problem, but I'll post it anyway) **TestFragmentAdapter.java** file

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(0);
        case 1:
            return SecondFragment.newInstance(1);
        case 2:
            return ThirdFragment.newInstance(2);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

That's my layout file to **FirstFragment.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/d_blue"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Layout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/d_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="SKIP"
            android:textColor="@color/light_font"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:textColor="@color/light_font"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile. Can you post your real code?

Comment: It compiles, I can assure you. I just have posted main snippets of my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using [`setCurrentItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) of the `ViewPager` instead of replacing the Fragments by yourself.

Comment: I have tried this before posting, doesn't help :/ I can't reach ViewPager from FirstFragment